# Error creating bean Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Spring boot application as a windows service, however the service does not boot because of the errors shown below.
(In intellij goes up and works normally, if running the direct Jar also works)

My pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.speedsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>bedelServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>bedel</name>
     <description>BWS</description>

     <parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
         <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <quartz.version>2.2.1</quartz.version>
        <jooq.version>3.9.1</jooq.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <logbackaccess.version>1.3.0-alpha4</logbackaccess.version>
        <mysql.version>6.0.3</mysql.version>
        <exec-maven-plugin>1.7</exec-maven-plugin>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>${logbackaccess.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.speedsoft.bws.BwsApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>

                  <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>

            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Class used to set environment variable settings

```
@Component
public class  ConfigClass {

    @Value("${bws.page.size}")
    private int pageSize;

    @Value("${bws.export.periodo}")
    private int periodoLetivo;

    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

      public int getPeriodoLetivo() {
        return periodoLetivo;
    }

    public void setPeriodoLetivo(int periodoLetivo) {
        this.periodoLetivo = periodoLetivo;
    }


    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(this.getDriverConnection());
            return DriverManager.getConnection(this.getStringConnection(), this.getUser(), this.getPassword());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Deploy error log

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

13-12-2018 15:54:22.733 [35m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.prepareRefresh - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6842775d: startup date [Thu Dec 13 15:54:22 BRST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
13-12-2018 15:54:25.147 [35m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
13-12-2018 15:54:25.163 [35m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol.log - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
13-12-2018 15:54:25.178 [35m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.a.catalina.core.StandardService.log - Starting service [Tomcat]
13-12-2018 15:54:25.178 [35m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine.log - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
13-12-2018 15:54:25.194 [35m[localhost-startStop-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.a.c.core.AprLifecycleListener.log - The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\CodeGear\Delphi2007\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Groovy\GROOVY~1.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]
13-12-2018 15:54:25.319 [35m[localhost-startStop-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].log - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
13-12-2018 15:54:25.319 [35m[localhost-startStop-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.s.web.context.ContextLoader.prepareWebApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2601 ms
13-12-2018 15:54:25.491 [35m[localhost-startStop-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean.addRegistration - Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
13-12-2018 15:54:25.506 [35m[localhost-startStop-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean.configure - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
13-12-2018 15:54:25.506 [35m[localhost-startStop-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean.configure - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
13-12-2018 15:54:25.506 [35m[localhost-startStop-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean.configure - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
13-12-2018 15:54:25.506 [35m[localhost-startStop-1][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean.configure - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
13-12-2018 15:54:25.569 [35m[main][0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bwsApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO' in value "${BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO}"
13-12-2018 15:54:25.569 [35m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.a.catalina.core.StandardService.log - Stopping service [Tomcat]
13-12-2018 15:54:25.583 [35m[localhost-startStop-1][0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.log - The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
13-12-2018 15:54:25.595 [35m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logAutoConfigurationReport - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
13-12-2018 15:54:25.598 [35m[main][0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bwsApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO' in value "${BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.speedsoft.bws.BwsApplication.main(BwsApplication.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO' in value "${BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:379)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO' in value "${BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:88)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:531)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:145)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Application properties

```
#ENVIRONMENT
bws.page.size=${BWS_PAGE_SIZE}
bws.export.periodo = ${BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO}
```

Comment: `bws.page.size` should be an integer.  I don't know what do you want to do with this `${BWS_PAGE_SIZE}`

Comment: Your two properties ${BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO} and ${BWS_PAGE_SIZE} in the application.properties, where are they being set?

Comment: @Rentius2407
they come from the windows environment variables, when I run the application through the IDE everything works as expected the problem is in deploy

Comment: Have you set those variables in the deployment environment?

Comment: @NicholasK 
Yes, I'm doing deploy to the same location that works by IDE

Comment: I think it isn't resolving the windows environment variables or variable.

Comment: @Rentius2407 but why does it work normally in intellij?

Comment: The environment variables are set at user level or system level?

Comment: The properties being set in Intellij is being resolved correctly. The Caused by: stacktrace talks about the ${BWS_EXPORT_PERIODO} property which lets me think there is something wrong with the environment variable.

Comment: @EugenCovaci dude, it seems that's right ... they're all user level ... I'm changing to see ... thank you all

Comment: It worked? .........

Comment: @EugenCovaci Yes man...
thank you very much